# Polymer core-localstorage - Loading pre-existing global js variable

Tags: polymer, core-elements

In the following stripped-down code example, shouldn't the core-localstorage element load the value of the global js variable `itemsApiURL' into {{value}}, so that it is passed into my-datasource-element when that custom element is prepared?  Or is the purpose of core-localstorage limited to writing values to localstorage?  Currently, as is, {{value}} is undefined on my-datasource-element's ready() event, despite it existing as a global variable (ideally set in an external js config file, not included in head as shown here).  I'm definitely not doing something right...perhaps my lack of comfort with js, or some sort of scoping/sequence of events issue.

Maybe there is an entirely better way to configure polymer app-wide variables/constants, so that values can be easily used my all of the applications elements, or at least passed around as element attributes via 2 way databinding?  That is really the more important question here I think...but either way I'm still confused as to how core-localstorage is meant to operate.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            this.itemsApiURL = "http://server:port/api/items";
        </script>

        <link rel="import" href="./components/platform/platform.js">
        <link rel="import" href="./components/core-localstorage/core-localstorage.html">
    </head>

    <body fullbleed unresolved>

        <template is="auto-binding">
            <core-localstorage name="itemsApiURL" value="{{value}}"></core-localstorage>

            <my-datasource-element url="{{value}}" items="{{items}}"><my-datasource-element>
        </template>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as possible, Polymer wants you to not have to worry about timing issues (aka listening for events as timing signals). In particular, because *element upgrade* preserves property values, events, and other element features, when you need to poke values into an element, you can often do so immediately.

E.g., in this case, you can simplify to:

```
<template is="auto-binding">
  <core-localstorage name="itemsApiURL"
                     value="{{itemsApiURL}}"></core-localstorage>
  <label for="inputElement">itemsApiURL:</label>
  <input type="text"
         id="inputElement"
         value="{{itemsApiURL}}"
         size="50">
</template>

<script>
  document.querySelector('template').itemsApiURL = 
    'http://server:port/api/items';
</script>
```

It might look like we are racing the `<script>` tag and the `<core-localstorage>` with regards to the value of `itemsApiURL`, but Polymer creates *asynchrony* between creation of the `<core-localstorage>` and the querying of the actual storage. This means that the script tag will always run first, which is what we are looking for.

Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/zuvet/2/edit

Remember that when testing, you may have to use the dev-tools to delete the localstorage entry to test the defaulting behavior.

P.S. auto-binding templates should probably have an explicit way to set property defaults, perhaps through attributes.

P.P.S. Looking at this example I discovered that `core-localstorage` has a bug. It's not supposed to store uninitialized values into the storage, but it only checks for `null` and not for `undefined` (https://github.com/Polymer/core-localstorage/issues/5).

Comment: Agreed.  Much more straightforward implementation.  Thanks for the added clarification as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're partway there.

One issue is that when using JavaScript to interact with variables inside `<template is="auto-binding">`, you do so via properties on the `<template>` element. If you're going to read values that are set inside the element, you need to wait for the [`template-bound`](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/databinding-advanced.html#autobinding) event to be fired.

Second, you should be setting your default value a bit differently. I also prefer not to use the variable name `value` for the published `value=` attribute, especially if you have a number of `<core-localstorage>` elements (they can't each publish their `value` attributes to a variable named `value`).

Here's a working example that captures what you're trying to do. ([Live version on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zucele/edit).) Whenever you change the value in the `<input type="text">` the updated value will be written to local storage, and the first time you visit the page, a default value of `"http://server:port/api/items"` is used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Polymer Demo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-localstorage/core-localstorage.html">

    <template is="auto-binding">
      <core-localstorage name="itemsApiURL"
                         value="{{itemsApiURL}}">
      </core-localstorage>
      <label for="inputElement">itemsApiURL:</label>
      <input type="text"
             id="inputElement"
             value="{{itemsApiURL}}"
             size="50">
    </template>

    <script>
      var template = document.querySelector('template');
      template.addEventListener('template-bound', function() {
        template.itemsApiURL = template.itemsApiURL || 'http://server:port/api/items';

        // You can do something with template.itemsApiURL
        // like use it to make an API call, etc.
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent Jeff.  Before I noticed your response, I implemented something that worked for me (see below).  If you have any insight on which might be the better/efficient/safe solution, feel free to comment.  I'd be interested to hear your thoughts on that.

Answer (score 0):

Before I saw Jeff's excellent and thorough response, I did the following which got things working (along the same lines as Jeff's solution, but acting on a different event):

First, I tweaked some of the existing element attributes/naming as follows:

```
<core-localstorage id="datasourceURL" name="itemsURL" value="{{itemsURL}}"></core-localstorage>

<my-datasource-element url="{{itemsURL}}" items="{{items}}"></my-datasource-element>
```

Then I added `onload="loadItemsURL()"` to the `body` tag.

Next, of course there was a need to script the loadItemsURL function and define an event listener.  In this case I decided to listen for `core-localstorage-load` (the core-element itself implements this event):

```
function loadItemsURL() {
        window.addEventListener('core-localstorage-load', function(event) {
           // Load base api URL for items collection from pre-existing global js variable (happens to be stored in external items.js)
           // This forces core-localstorage element to refresh its value (and populate polymer {{itemsURL}} )
           // in turn triggering datasource element to run ajax call
           // (as it happens to be set to 'auto' get when it's URL attribute or params change)
           this.datasourceURL.value = this.itemsURL;
        });
    }
```

That did the trick for me, as would Jeff's excellent solution above. However, perhaps Jeff can shed some light on why one method/event might be more efficient, or preferred than the other.

Comment: It's more in keeping with how `<template is="auto-binding">` works to set properties directly on the template element that correspond to the variables used inside the template. And rather than listening specifically for `core-localstorage-load` I'd recommend listening for `template-bound` and dealing with *all* variable properties then. It will scale better as the number of Polymer elements on your page increases.